# Displaying icon larger than 32x32 in dialog box

Tags: winapi, win32gui

Hi I created a dialog box within win32:

```
ABOUTBOX DIALOG DISCARDABLE 32, 32, 180, 100
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON "OK",IDOK,66,80,50,14
    ICON "ID_MYICON_2",IDC_STATIC,0,0,48,48
    CTEXT "comment1",IDC_STATIC,40,12,100,8
    CTEXT "comment2",IDC_STATIC,7,40,166,8
    CTEXT "comment3",IDC_STATIC,7,52,166,8
END
```

The icon file contains different sizes of images i.e. 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 etc however the code above only allows it do be displayed as 32x32. Even if i change it to

```
    ICON "ID_MYICON_2",IDC_STATIC,0,0,16,16
```

.. it still shows as 32x32. How do you fully control icon size? My original intention was to display a bmp.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you only include a 48x48 icon file in your *.ico?

Answer (score 2):

It is behavior by design. See [Static Control Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The style ignores the CreateWindow parameters nWidth and nHeight; the
>   control automatically sizes itself to accommodate the icon. **As it uses
>   the LoadIcon function, the SS_ICON style can load only icons of
>   dimensions SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON**. This restriction can be bypassed
>   by using the SS_REALSIZEIMAGE style in addition to SS_ICON.

Also, nothing prevents you from loading 48x48 icon programmatically and passing it to the control.